# Compiling error of pcre-8.30 on Ubuntu

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, libtool

I met an error when trying to compile pcre-8.30.tar.gz on Ubuntu 10.04, don't know what is happening.

```
ciphor@MyUbuntu:~/work/pcre-8.30$ make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ciphor/work/pcre-8.30'
  CXX    pcrecpp.lo
libtool: compile: unrecognized option `-DHAVE_CONFIG_H'
libtool: compile: Try `libtool --help' for more information.
make[1]: *** [pcrecpp.lo] Error 1
make[1]:Leaving directory `/home/ciphor/work/pcre-8.30'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I read the Makefile and found the following line:

```
LTCOMPILE = $(LIBTOOL) $(AM_V_lt) --tag=CC $(AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS) \
    $(LIBTOOLFLAGS) --mode=compile $(CC) $(DEFS) \
    $(DEFAULT_INCLUDES) $(INCLUDES) $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) \
    $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
```

wherein $(DEFS) is the "-DHAVE_CONFIG_H" option. I guess it is an option for gcc, not for libtool, right?

It seems that the error is around here, but how to solve it?

Comment: Could you check the values of CXX, CXXCPP and ac_ct_CXX in the Makefile? Are they all `=g++`? Is `g++` installed?

Comment: Yes, you are right, g++ is not installed.

Comment: Did installing it solve your problem? Might as well make this an answer, if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `g++` is installed, and that the values of `CXX`, `CXXCPP` and `ac_ct_CXX` in the Makefile are set to `g++`.